# Strugling with if, empty, and, or,

Tags: php, if-statement, string

The following script should create an error when date_enabled is 2 and one of the three variables is empty. When day is empty for example, the script still doesn't echo the sentence.
Does anybody sees the problem?

```
$year = $_POST['date-year'];
$month = $_POST['date-month'];
$day = $_POST['date-day'];
$date_enabled = 2;     
if ((($date_enabled ==2)) && ((empty($year) || empty($day) || empty($month)))){
            echo "You didn't enter a valid date";
            }
```

UPDATE - When I perform the following script it echos: its empty its empty (function). Which means that empty and the function isEmpty, which I created because of the advice of @Expert System , also works.

```
if (empty($day)){
    echo "its empty";
    }
if (!isset($day)){
    echo "its not set";
    }
if (isEmpty($day)){
    echo "its empty (function)";
    }
```

UPDATE AGAIN - The script above works indeed correctly. The problem lays with my form. It works fine now and thanks for your help.

Comment: `print_r($_POST);`. Also, why do you use double parenthesis?

Comment: try isset() instead of empty.

Comment: But I want to peform the echo when one of the three is empty. Not when they are not empty.

Comment: By isset() i mean use !isset().

Comment: @Tom Groot: Have you tried echoing the values of the three variables ?

Comment: Be aware that you will acceppt invalid dates by design: "31th Feb. of Foobar" is valid. More security comes if you use strtotime http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php and check for it´s outcome.

Comment: @ExpertSystem Yes I did, when I put selected a year it echoed the year and when I did not it didn't. So that's alright isn't it?

Comment: @TomGroot: Did you try my proposed solution ? What does it print ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the definition of "empty" in your question is unclear. If empty in your question means zero-length string, then **empty** function is not the right one for you.

empty() definition from PHP doucment

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is
>   considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.
>   empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

Maybe this custom function will work in your context

```
function isEmpty($var) {
    return !isset($var) || ($var == '');
}
```

Then

```
if (($date_enabled == 2) && 
    (isEmpty($year) || isEmpty($day) || isEmpty($month))){
    echo "You didn't enter a valid date";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
$year = isSet($_POST["date-year"]) ? $_POST["date-year"] : "";
$month = isSet($_POST["date-month"]) ? $_POST["date-month"] : "";
$day = isSet($_POST["date-day"]) ? $_POST["date-day"] : "";
$date_enabled = 2;
if ((($date_enabled ==2)) && ((empty($year) || empty($day) || empty($month)))){
    echo "You didn't enter a valid date";
}
```

The problem might be the error of level `E_NOTICE` raised when you try to access an undefined index in `$_POST` array.
This shoukd notcause a problem (i.e. stop execution) with theususl/default configuration options, but with yours it might (just guessing).

Comment: I think it should be isset()  not isSet()

Comment: Function-names in PHP are case-**insensitive**. I prefer to use camel-case (used to it from Java :)). So, both are correct - I just find camel-case more readable.

Comment: @ExpertSystem And I prefer using the functions like I read them in the manual. So that uGLy CaSE is not confusing me.